# JTextField - Reset Border to System Default

Tags: java, linux, swing, user-interface, border

I am trying to color the `Border` of a `JTextField` red and then change it back to "normal" later on. When I am using Linux (furthermore Ubuntu), the initial `Border` differs from the `Border` that you get by using `UIManager.getBorder("TextField.border");` one of them is a `SynthBorder` and one is a `FieldBorder`. The "correct" one would be the `SynthBorder`.

SSCCE:

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main
{
  private static boolean switched;

  public static void main( final String[] args )
      throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException
  {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName() );

    JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Test border change" );
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout( new BoxLayout( frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS ) );
    JTextField tf = new JTextField();
    JButton button = new JButton( "Switch" );
    button.addActionListener( action ->
    {
      if ( switched )
      {
        tf.setBorder( UIManager.getBorder( "TextField.border" ) );
        switched = !switched;
      }
      else
      {
        tf.setBorder( BorderFactory.createLineBorder( Color.RED ) );
        switched = !switched;
      }
    } );
    frame.getContentPane().add( tf );
    frame.getContentPane().add( button );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible( true );
  }
}
```

I have already tried:

- using `JComponent.updateUI()` (no effect)
- nulling the border (ruins the layout)
- preserving it (not a proper way)

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset/remove a border in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726808/reset-remove-a-border-in-swing)

Comment: I have tried that already, works fine in the example, but throws exceptions in the productive usecase, because of the eventing. I might look furhter into that though.

Comment: One comment on an answer in the above link suggests to call `setBorder(null)` before calling `updateUI()` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you replace the Border try using:

```
Border uiBorder = BorderUIResource( BorderFactory.createLineBorder( Color.RED ) );
tf.setBorder( uiBorder );
```

When you use any wrapper class with "UIResource" this tell the LAF the component is part of the LAF and not a custom implementation

Then to restore the Border:

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI( tf );
```

Hopefully this will fake the UI into resetting the LAF properties, specifically the Border.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Set the LAF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#dynamic) for more information.

Of course this is not as efficient as simply saving the Border and resetting it as all properties of the text field will be updated bye the `updatComponentTreeUI(...)` (if this works).

Still don't see why you can't save the Border. You could use the `putClientProperty(...)` method of the `JComponent` class to save the Border and then restore it using the `getClientProperty(...)` method.

You could even automate this by using adding a `PropertyChangeListener` to listen for a change in the border. When an event is generated if the `getClientProperty(...)` returns null, then you save the old value from the `PropertyChangeEvent`.

Comment: I'll be preserving using the put/getClientProperty methods. Also, uodateComponentTreeUI works well, but preserving sadly fits my case better ;D

Answer (score 4):

You can get the *default border* in the `UIManager` with this code:

```
jTextField2.setBorder(UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getDefaults().getBorder("TextField.border"));
```

Comment: This is a fundamental solution, also for setting borders on controls that lack them.
I've not been able to find this anywhere else - excellent, thank you!

Comment: This even works when using FlatLaf themes. Basically resets it to the default border and style i.e. theme applied

Answer (score 2):

```
yourJTextField.setBorder(new JTextField().getBorder());
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the border right after creating the component to save it, and set it again later.

```
Border defaultBorder = tf.getBorder();
...
tf.setBorder(defaultBorder);
```

Comment: Preserving is not an option ;D

Comment: @ScriptKiddy, `Preserving is not an option` - why not?